# Gaussian weighted distance between pixel amplitudes: motivations and sources?

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, reference-request, distance-metrics, signals-history

In several image processing papers, and for instance in [Random Walks for Image Segmentation](http://www.cns.bu.edu/~lgrady/grady2006random.pdf) (2006) by Leo Grady, changes in image intensities are turned into edge weights. In some fields, it is called *[Geographically Weighted Regression](https://www.mailman.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/geographically-weighted-regression)*. This applies to graphs too, and has become popular for instance in non-local means denoising algorithms. A popular weighting is Gaussian. Quoting Grady (Equation 1, page 1772):

> In this work, we have preferred (**for empirical reasons**) the **typical**
>   Gaussian weighting function given by: 
>   $$ w_{ij} =  \exp{\left(-\beta(g_i-g_j)^2\right)} $$ 
>   where $g_i$ indicates the
>   image intensity at pixel $i$

My questions are:

- what are the earliest/most authoritative references for such a **typical** Gaussian weighting?
- since Gaussian models are not considered the most appropriate for structured image modelling, what are the non-trivial "**empirical**" benefits of such a weighting, with respect to, eg, a near-Gaussian bisquare function?
  $$w_{ij} = (1-\beta(g_i-g_j)^2)^2$$

Comment: I'm obviously no expert on image segmentation, but wouldn't using a $\beta$ in the exponent practically allow to integrate gamma correction into the weight calculation?

Comment: An interesting comment. So far, I thought of it as a scale parameter, to promote interaction between close pixel values that could belong to the same almost flat areas

Comment: hm, yeah, that makes "empirically" sense :) Also, maybe the Gaussian-shaping comes from the information theory idea that Gaussian-distributed noise has the highest differential entropy, but I'm not sure how that would help you

Comment: I shall had some bits found in early papers by Perona etc. They draw some connexions with robust statistics, using Tukey biweight functions for instance

Comment: For your second question, I would suggest that the Gaussian is an oversimplification of the contribution of each pixel to its neighbours. An oversimplification of the typical `sinc` that is supposed to be centred on each pixel, for ["sampled reconstruction" to work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula#Stationary_random_processes). Smooth image, low freqs, small grads, higher prob to "walk" to neighbour. At the scales involved, Gaussian is probably "good enough" to provide edge weights.

Comment: @A_A good point; another reason might be that "historically", DoG might have proven to be a viable edge detector, and thus, using Gaussians felt "natural".

Comment: In contrast with the standard DoG, keep in mind that this does not depend on pixel locations (only intensities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not an exact answer, but I'll to give a direction.

What you are using is essentially an [RBF-Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel). First, it has a ready interpretation as a similarity measure (satisfies Mercer's conditions). In essence, other such kernels can be used. For instance, an inner product (linear kernel) would define an angular distance between pixels/features. For a deeper understanding, I would dive in the literature of kernels.

Having said that, the simplest form of such relations are called [inverse distance weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) (Grady could have used this as well), where any identity like $1/d(g_i, g_j)^p$ can be used. These methods also cover a wide spectrum.

Comment: Bringing the Mercer conditions back, and linking to Gaussian RBF is a good point.